# Kernel panic error after upgrade - how to boot from backup kernel?

Tags: kernel, kubuntu

I was running Kubuntu v14 (I think) just fine on a home built desktop. I applied the most recent updates and all of the sudden, when I try to boot the machine, it is going into a black screen with a bunch of dump codes ending in the following:

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on  unknown block(0,0)
```

Someone on a different Linux forum suggested that the problem might be "a kernel upgrade gone wrong" and suggested I boot from a backup kernel.

Can anyone explain how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Sure.  Use the method explained in the answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version